# Prove sequence using induction

Tags: induction

$a_1=1$, $a_{n+1} = 3 a_n^2$.

Prove for all positive integers, $a_n\leq{3^{2^n}}$ using induction.

My work so far:

Base case is true (1 < 9)

Induction Hypothesis: $a_k\leq{3^{2^k}}$

IS: prove that n = k+1 is true

I'm stuck because I just can't seem to prove the induction step. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: square and multiply by 3 on both sides:$$a_{k+1}=3a_k^2\leq 3^{2^{k+1}+1}$$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee but the induction step is prove $a_{k+1}\leq3^{2^{k+1}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to show the stronger condition

$$a_n\leq{3^{2^n-1}}(\leq{3^{2^n}})$$

and therefore assuming as Induction Hypothesis $a_k\leq{3^{2^k-1}}$ we have

$$a_{k+1}=3a_k^2\stackrel{Ind. Hyp.}\leq 3\cdot (3^{2^{k}-1})^2={3^{2^{k+1}-1}}$$

Refer also to the related

- [Prove that $1/n+1/(n+1)+\dots+(1/2n)>2/3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2975250/505767)

Comment: Because $2^{k+1} >2^k+1$ for $k>0$

Comment: @Mason Yes of course, that's why in short.

Comment: I don't understand how you got $3(a_k)^2\leq3\cdot{3^{2^k}}$ using the IH. What happened to the squared on $3(a_k)^2$?

Comment: @HarrySmith Ops sorry, you ar eright, I fox that.

Answer (score 0):

Induction proves $a_n=3^{2^n-1}$, which implies the inequality.